# Trying to remove modal background with click event

Tags: jquery, css

I'm testing some code that in the end will be a modal popup-window with a half transparent background. The problem is that I want to remove the background class `.modal-overlay` by clicking on the background and not only on the closing button that I'm going to have in the popup window. I have tested two ways to check if something happens when I click on the background, but nothing happens! What have I done wrong or missed?

jQuery:

```
var appendthis =  ("<div class='modal-overlay modal-close'></div>");

$('#open-popup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);

});

$(".modal-overlay").on("click", function(){
    alert("Closing!?");
});

$(".modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
    alert("Closing?");
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(".modal-overlay").remove();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.modal-overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some HTML as well?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment! I'm building a WordPress theme. Too much HTML code to paste here I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code above is that you are defining the click event handler for an element that doesn't exist at that time. And when you create it later, that element doesn't have the click handler attached to it.

You have to use delegated events to achieve what you want ([read more about it in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)). That way, the click event handler will be attached to the element when it is created:

```
$(document).on("click", "selector-for-element-created-later", function(e) { ... });
```

---

Applied to your code it would be like this (I replaced the `alert` with a `confirm`):

```js
var appendthis =  ("<div class='modal-overlay modal-close'></div>");

$('#open-popup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    
});

$(document).on("click", ".modal-close, .modal-overlay", function() {
    if (confirm("Closing?")) {
        $(".modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(".modal-overlay").remove();
        });
    }
});

/* 
// or this

$(document).on("click", ".modal-overlay", function(){
    alert("Closing!?");
});
*/
```

```css
.modal-overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="open-popup">Open Popup</button>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your interesting answer! I have not thought about what you are writing about. Great to learn some new things! I guess if don't create the new div with append within the click event function and instead create it at start outside the click event function, my code should work? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I believe in that case your code should work fine (if you don't do the remove part). Another alternative would be to move the `$(".modal-overlay").on("click",...)` right after the append.